# Keep point position between re-opening files with recentf/ido

Tags: point, recentf

It's hard to say what was broken in my .emacs but with new Emacs 25.1.1 after opening file from `recentf` point is placed at the beginning of buffer whereas with Emacs 24 it opens in last viewed location.

Any suggestion to make Emacs 25 place point in last viewed position between file re-opening?

So this: http://hg.defun.work/dot-emacs/file/tip/.emacs-my work in Emacs 24 and doesn't in Emacs 25...

Comment: I don't think `recentf.el` has any provision for saving and restoring point. But `saveplace.el` does. Did you perhaps use that before, and are not using it now? See option `save-place`.

Comment: Well, I see from your init file that you do seem to turn on `save-place`. See if you can repro the problem with `emacs -Q` (Emacs 25), with just a minimal init file that turns on use of both recentf and save-place. If you can, consider filing a bug report.

Comment: I managed to resolve issue with your hint! I added `save-place` 10 years ago and forgot its name...

Comment: Good to hear. It's easy to forget all the stuff we load and what each piece does.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that I used deprecated way for activating minor mode (this works across Emacs 21-24):

```
(setq-default save-place t)
(require 'saveplace)
```

Today way to activate this minor mode is:

```
(save-place-mode 1)
```

Thanks to **Drew** for hint!

Comment: I think you can accept your own answer here to close out the question.